# python 2.7 rename values within list

Tags: python, pandas, import

When import several csvs and I save it within an array, the name for all files that were imported is `q=[Dataframe, Dataframe,Dataframe,Dataframe,Dataframe,Dataframe,Dataframe,Dataframe]`, I would like to change the name using like base the name of the file.

```
files_array_Q = []
files_array_F = []
files_array_MRG =[]

for files in files_import_Q :
    qs_matrix = pd.read_csv(files, delimiter=" ", header=None)
    files_array_Q.append(qs_matrix)

for files in files_import_F :
    in_fam = pd.read_csv(files, delimiter=" ", header=None)
    files_array_F.append(in_fam)
```

for example read files with names `file1.Q file2.Q file3.Q files4.Q`

within the array  `files_array_Q = [files1, file2, files3, file4]`

Comment: What do you mean by name? Objects in lists don't have names. Do you mean keys in a dictionary? Or do you want to change class names, i.e. what you see in console if you call `print()`?

Comment: What do you mean by name? R= name of file that was imported, yes I want to change class name within files_array_Q.

Comment: Recommend updating to Python 3.

Comment: elements on list don't have names - they have only numbers - `files_array_Q[0]`, `files_array_Q[1]`, etc. If you really need names then use dictionary and you will use strings as names `files_array_Q["file1"]`, `files_array_Q["file2"]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Pandas string split function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html). This solution assumes that the file names do not have extraneous periods.

```
q_list = pd.DataFrame(['file1.Q', 'file2.Q', 'file3.Q'], columns=['files'])

# split into file, type
q_split = pd.DataFrame(q.files.str.split('.',1).tolist())

# now get only the first column:
q_name_only = q_split[q_split.columns[0]]
```

You can combine these two steps into one line using Pandas [iloc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) to choose the column by its integer location:

```
q_name_only = pd.DataFrame(q_list.files.str.split('.',1).tolist()).iloc[:,0]
```